# Archivie license with regards to Enterprise Exchange 2010 SP1 versus Standard?

Tags: exchange-2010, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm currently in the process of upgrading our 2007 Exchange environment to 2010 SP1.  One of the neat features I've seen is the archiving feature, since we (like many) have issues with users having way too large/many .pst files.  I've built the new server, it's standing up beside our currnet 2007 server and all is working fine so far.  I've migrated myself over as a test and can send/receive, etc.  I am now just kind of checking out the other features it has and notice when I click on properties of my account that it states "Online archives are a premium feature and require an Exchange Enterprise CAL to enable it for the mailbox".  Just to get my terminology straight I was hoping for some clarification.  I have installed Exchange Standard 2010 on this server, not Exchange Enterprise 2010, is this saying that I would have needed to install Enterprise for this to work, or is it stating that this feature is an "Enterprise level" feature that I'll need to contact MS for to get additional licensing (with cost associated)?  Just wanting to make sure if I need to talk to them to go further, or back off and try to install Exchange Enterprise vs Standard (hoping not!).  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you would not need the "Enterprise Edition" of Exchange server, you just need the [add-on "Enterprise" client access license](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/licensing-exchange-server-email.aspx#Exchange2010CAL) for every user you need the personal archive feature for. Also take a look at the [Office Outlook help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/license-requirements-for-personal-archive-and-retention-policies-HA102576659.aspx) for details on the featureset and prerequisites on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up!  I'll contact our MS rep about the licensing.